# Starting remote virtual interface (rvictl) on MacBook for packet trace of iPhone is failing without error

Tags: packet, packet-sniffers, packet-capture, ios15, xcode13

I am hoping for tips troubleshooting why `rvictl` is not working on my MacBook Pro. Running `rvictl -s <udid>` yields `Starting device 000****0-0****5****D****E [FAILED]` without telling me why it is failing or giving an error message.

I have identified my iPhone UDID as `000****0-0****5****D****E` (censored) using `xcrun xctrace list devices`. I have updated my Xcode to version `13.2.1` and my iPhone to version `15.3.1`. I have restarted both my laptop and my iPhone 11. My MacBook Pro is version `12.0.1`. I have tried running `sudo rvictl -s 000****0-0****5****D****E`.

Is there a way to get more information from `rvictl` as to why it is failing? E.g. a verbose option? Any thoughts on what I could try to get to the bottom of this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Just restarting my computer was not good enough. I had to restart from `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General` where there was a small `Restart` button. That definitely could have been made more clear in the documentation.